# In Xcode, how to move folder from project navigator to another project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a huge project, part of which looks like,

[image]

I want to move this entire ThirdParty folder to another project. How can I do this quick?

I cannot just drag folders in the Finder, since the project navigator's file representation is not the exact match of that in the file system(Finder). For example, those .xcodeproject are not actually in the same level with those folders in the file system.

I can obviously drag them from the Finder folder by folder and adjust them file by file, but that would be a huge headache. Is there any way to "export" and "import" this project navigation view's substructure?